# Show activity indicator for 3 sec in swift 2.0 Table view

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I placed one custom `Activity Indicator` to my table view and I named it: `activityIndicator`. I also have one action button. When I press that button, the activity indicator should show for 3 seconds and after that it should hide. How to do that in swift 2.0

```
@IBAction func RefineButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can try this for a single function implementation

```
@IBAction func RefineButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = false

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
         self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
         self.activityIndicator.hidden = true

    };
}
```

Comment: in this i also need to reload my table view like ` self.tableview.reload()`... inside that dispatch can i reload my table view??

Comment: i am facing one issue !. When i ad custom activity indicator. And added all code for action. I am getting one error that `  The activityIndicator outlet from the ViewController to the UIActivityIndicatorView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. `. How can i added iboutlet activity indicator to my table view?? any other idea to do ??

Comment: i think thats because you are adding an outlet form a tableview cell to a viewcontroller, which wont work since the cells get recycled so it will be ambiguous which activity indicator you want, i think you will have to assign the outlet of the activity indicator to your custom cell, and access it through there, rather than in your viewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

First create one method in your class with name `hideActivityIndicator` as below:

```
func hideActivityIndicator()
{
    activityIndi.hidden = true
}
```

Then call that method in perform selector where you want to call. i.e on your button click event as below :

```
self.performSelector("hideActivityIndicator", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 works as follows:

```
func hideActivityIndicator() {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.perform(#selector(IAPViewController.hideActivityIndicator), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
}
```

Naturally, this is what I needed to use it for, so modify it to meet your needs